# Are there any windows clients for tdengine with GUI?

Tags: tdengine

Are there any windows clients for tdengine with GUI?
Such as windows sql server or navicat.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/skye0207/TDengineGUI may be a good answer for you.

It's third-party a simple TDengine DeskTop Manager.

Answer (score 0):

qStudio is a free SQL GUI, it allows running SQL scripts, easy browsing of tables, charting and exporting of results. It works on every operating system, with every database including TDEngine.

https://www.timestored.com/qstudio/database/tdengine

[image: tdengine qstudio gui]

Transparency: I am the main author of qStudio for the last 12+ years.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)